# How to count "type" in crystal report C#?

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have 1 report with 4 cols: Id,name,grade,type. col "type" as "good","bad". Now i want to count how many type "good" or how many type "bad" in report, help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a formula field called "Counter" with logic something like:

```
if ({type}="Good") then 1
else 0
```

Then place Counter in the Details of your report.

Then right-mouse click on the "Counter" formula field in your report and select Insert --> Summary, and select the option "Sum". This will insert a sum at the bottom of your report.